# components on my tableview cell are not visible

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

I am building a table view contains just a button, with different labels.

I am using a table view to present a list of buttons.

this a structure containing names of the buttons.

```
struct post {
   let name : String
}
```

I have pushed data from firebase to structure post.

```
var posts = [post]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as Any as! String).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                   // print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    self.posts.insert(post(name: document.documentID), at: 0)
                }
                self.contents.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

these are normal functions of table view

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return posts.count
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cellview
        cell.programnames.titleLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
```

cellview.swift is designed as follow

```
class cellview: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var programnames: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
```

Please tell me my mistake in it. Button 'programnames' are not visible in table view in simulator

Comment: @AamirR but button's label are not changed and only one row is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things missing that could be causing `UITableViewDataSource` not to be called

1. You need to set `UITableView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad`
2. You need to register `cellview.xib` in `viewDidLoad`, like so:

   ```
   contents.register(UINib(nibName: "cellview", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   ```
3. Optionals are for the reason that these can be `nil` and if it did your app will crash, avoid force unwrapping optionals `!`, here is example `guard` statement with optional chaining

   ```
   guard err == nil, let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
       // error handling here
       return
   }

   self.posts = documents.map { post(name: $0.documentID) }
   ```
4. I saw in your code using `posts.insert(..., at: 0)` which will reverse the array, if its on purpose use following instead:

   ```
   self.posts = documents.map({ post(name: $0.documentID) }).reversed()
   ```

Comment: You are adding `document.documentID` in array `posts`, can you print it what it contains `print(document.documentID)`

Comment: I did, its giving the name of documents in firebase database. @AamirR

Comment: is the syntax to change the label of buttons from outlet is correct or not. @AamirR

Comment: Please notice this line `contents.register(UINib(nibName: "cellview", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`